# Get dynamic AJAX URL with Jquery "ajaxSend"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If you go to this website: `http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/` 
You wil see an example where on the click of a button an ajax call is made to this URL: `/ajax/ajax_info.txt`

You can see the request in console. I'm trying to get this URL with Jquery like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(document).ajaxSend(function(evt, request, settings) {
  alert("Starting request at " + settings.url + ".");
});

});
```

The problem is that it is not alerting anything. Why is that? I'm testing this in two ways, first: implementing the jquery library and code in the console and second: scraping with PHP and injecting the code. Neither method is working. So how can I get the last URL?

Comment: ps. The code works for some other websites like: `usatoday.com` although not all url's are retrieved.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/.  My bad.  So based on the docs, when do you trigger the call?

Comment: you trigger the call when you click the button...

Comment: I'm not seeing that js here.

Comment: If youre trying to tell me something please get to it already...

Comment: I'm trying to tell you I don't see enough info here to see anything working. The w3c school sample, when you click try it yourself looks like this - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first.  I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, or how to replicate the error (or lack of) you are seeing.  Can you create a jsFiddle or something that has more code, so we can understand, and attempt to correct whatever issue you are having?

Comment: When you go the first URL I mentioned you will see "Let AJAX change this text" beneath this text there is a button, click on that button and you will see (in your console under the tab networks) a call being made to this url: /ajax/ajax_info.txt So Im tryin to get that addres when the call is being made and then put it in to an alert. Let me know if youre having trouble

Comment: Ok - so where is the above code being called?

Comment: What code..? You mean my code from the question..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event being fired on the page you have listed is a jquery ajax event - from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/).

> Description: Attach a function to be executed before an Ajax request
>   is sent. This is an Ajax Event.

The page you are trying to test the code on is using plain ol' javascript and *not* jquery, therefore, the ajax event is never fired, and the ajaxSend function is never triggered.

You would need to get the data via a jquery ajax call to get the correct functionality.

Comment: Im doing the alert on AJAX call

Comment: Ok Thank you very much:) Do you think there is an alternative to retrieve _any_ HTTP request being made, either Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: There mignt be something wrong with your answer on second thoughts...Jquery IS Javascript, it shouldn't matter, its basicaly an AJAX call, it doesnt matter how you write the code..

Comment: It completely matters.  Try it with all jquery.  The events are not getting fired by the jquery lib.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Any idea on how to retrieve any HTTP request being made?